# Is there any affordable cloud storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, youtube-api, storage, offlineapps, cloud-storage

I'm developing a web/mobile app similar to dropbox or drive, but I'm finding problems about storage cost.

As I said, my application lets the user storage files and retrieve it later, but my users pay only one time, so I've found Amazon S3 and GCS too expensive, because they charge every month, also they charge per transaction and download bandwith, so it would be unaffordable.

In my search I've wondered how could work a website like youtube considering that the cost is too much.

I've found Backblaze and It would be cheaper for my needs, but still goes very expensive.

I've considered using Youtube API for upload videos and reduce costs, but my application would work offline too (It would sync frequently) so I don't think youtube works for offline playing.

Could you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but your situation is of interest to me as I am asked this constantly by customers. What is the cheapest solution, and not what is the most appropriate solution?

When you try to reduce storage costs too far, reliability will usually drop significantly. The cost for S3 is dirt cheap to me and Backblaze is 4 times cheaper (I don't have personal experience with Backblaze).

Think about your business model a bit. If the service that you are offering cannot offer the reliability that will be required, you will quickly fail. A couple of data loss situations and poof, your business is gone.